# Explain Matlab Code

Tags: algorithm, matlab, particle-swarm

This code is part of PSO Algorithm, in MATLAB. What is the type of **empty_particle** and **particle**?

```
npop=100;

empty_particle.position=[];
empty_particle.velocity=[];
empty_particle.cost=[];
empty_particle.pbest=[];
empty_particle.pbestcost=[];

particle=repmat(empty_particle,npop,1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

empty_particle will be a structure which is then has entries initialised with a 0x0 array

They can either be created via the struct command

```
empty_particle = struct()
empty_particle.position=[];
```

or via matlab typecasting when you attempt to access an attribute

```
empty_particle.position=[];
```

if you type **whos** into the command window it will tell you a lot about the workspace variables.